# how to get view when phone is ringing

Tags: java, android

I want to customize the phone ringing view and show and show a textView .now how I can access that view and customize it ? or if I cant access it what I can do for show an TextView in that view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an app,and extend the BroadcastListener service in the activity,and provide the layout as you want for that activity
1) declare broadcast receiver in AndroidManifest.xml

```
     <receiver android:name=".MainActivity">   
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

also this permission

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Your main MainActivity.java should be something like this file

```
    public class MainActivity extends BroadcastReceiver {

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

try {
           // TELEPHONY MANAGER class object to register one listner
            TelephonyManager tmgr = (TelephonyManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            //Create Listner
            MyPhoneStateListener PhoneListener = new MyPhoneStateListener();

            // Register listener for LISTEN_CALL_STATE
            tmgr.listen(PhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Phone Receive Error", " " + e);
    }

}

private class MyPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        Log.d("MyPhoneListener",state+"   incoming no:"+incomingNumber);

        if (state == 1) {

            String msg = "New Phone Call Event. Incomming Number : "+incomingNumber;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(pcontext, msg, duration);
            toast.show();

        }
    }
}
```

}

This code will show a toast when phone call is received,you can change the layout file and display according to your needs.

Comment: its context of your current activity,just replace "pcontext" with "getApplicationContext()" or else "YOUR_ACTIVITY_NAME.this"